# Spring ErrorController issue with Spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot

I am stuck configuring Spring Error mapping with Spring security in Spring Boot 1.3.5 app.

I have follow security config class:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("admin").password("123").roles("ADMIN");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .httpBasic().and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/admin").hasRole("ADMIN").and()
                .csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

And ExceptionController :

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorController;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;

@Controller
public class ExceptionController implements ErrorController {
    private static final String ERROR_PATH = "/error";

    @RequestMapping(value = ERROR_PATH)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    public String error(HttpServletResponse response) {
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        return "redirect:/";
    }

    @Override
    public String getErrorPath() {
        return ERROR_PATH;
    }

}
```

/admin secure page works fine **without ExceptionController** . But when I adding it, login form not appearing, I have tried a lot of things, such as ControllerAdvice, but nothing seems work for me. What's proper solution here ?